# Why does this form submit?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an issue, i want to mail via AJAX, and my issue is that my form keeps submitting.
For some reason it refreshes with all the form into in the URL, but i have not send anything with GET ?

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="ajaxEmail();
        return false;" >
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Name" maxlength="1000" onfocus="this.value = this.value == 'Name' ? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value == '' ? 'Name' : this.value;" />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="Email" maxlength="1000" onfocus="this.value = this.value == 'Email' ? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value == '' ? 'Email' : this.value;" />
    <input type="text" id="subject"  value="Subject" maxlength="2000" onfocus="this.value = this.value == 'Subject' ? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value == '' ? 'Subject' : this.value;" />
    <textarea name="Message" id="body" maxlength="40000" onfocus="this.value = this.value == 'Message' ? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value == '' ? 'Message' : this.value;">Message</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send" class="submit-button"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function ajaxEmail() {
    $('#emailMsgResp').hide();
    $('#emailMsgBody').hide();

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var emailForm = $('#email').val();
    var subject = $('#subject').val();
    var message = $('#body').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // Can be "GET"
        url: "../ajaxMail.php",
        data: {
        name: name,
        emailFrom: emailFrom,
        subject: subject,
        message: message
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

        if (data['response'] == 1) {

            $('#emailMsgResp').show();
            $('#emailMsgResp').append('<div class="skill3" id="emailMsgBody" style="width:325px; height: 38px; margin: 0px auto;"><p>Thank you for contacting me' + data['response'] + '</p></div>');
            return false;

        } else if (data['response'] == 0) {

            $('#emailMsgResp').show();
            $('#emailMsgResp').append('<div class="skill3" id="emailMsgBody" style="width:325px; height: 38px; margin: 0px auto;"><p>Error: Please use your own client and write to contact@ivan-ristic.com</p></div>');
            return false;
        }
    }
    });
    return false;
});
```

ajaxMail.php

```
$email_it_to = 'mymail@mymail.com';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_from = $_POST['emailFrom'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = $_POST['message'];

if(!isset($name) || !isset($email_from) || !isset($subject) || !isset($body)) {
    $response = 0;

} else {

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_subject = "Contact Form: ".stripslashes($subject);
    $email_message = "Below is a message submitted by '".stripslashes($name);
    $email_message .="' on ".date("d/m/Y")." at ".date("H:i")."\n\n";
    $email_message .= stripslashes($body);

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    if (mail($email_it_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {

        $response = 1;
    } else {

        $response = 0;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: `$(function ajaxEmail() { /* code */ });` means to execute that function when the page has loaded. If you're using jQuery, take advantage of its event binding, by giving the `<form>` an `id` and using `$("#form_id").on("submit", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* Other code */ });` instead of the `onsubmit` attribute

Comment: when is the first submission? on the enter key?

Comment: Ian's suggestion worked, now im only lacking a AJAX response for some reason, ah well, il look in to it, thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 7):

You are assigning your function as a document ready handler, so it gets called as soon as the page is ready. You have:

```
$(function ajaxEmail() {
   /* your code */
});
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function ajaxEmail() {
    /* your code */
});
```

What you *should* have:

```
function ajaxEmail() {
   /* your code */
}
```

That would make your function a global function that can be called from an inline event attribute.

Or, since you are using jQuery anyway, remove the inline `onsubmit=...` handler from your form and assign it with jQuery instead:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        /* your other function contents here */
    });
});
```

Of course it would be better to give your form an id attribute and use `$("#yourFormId").submit(...)` rather than using `$("form").submit(...)` (which assigns the same handler to all forms on the page).

Comment: I removed the onsubmit part, its only a <form> tag now, but i still get a refresh and a url like this when i click submit:

http://www.mydomain.com/?name=asddsa&email=dsadsadsa%40live.dksda&Message=sdadsa

I have no clue why it refreshes with a GET

Comment: This is not the root of the issue, since alert('whatever'); return false; in the onsubmit property worked before, but it wouldnt make an ajax call

Comment: Did you remove the `$(` part (and it's closing `);`) as per the first part of my answer?